# Understanding the behaviour of substring in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, substring

I am new to postgresql guys. I tried to use `substring` function, while trying some examples I've noticed "awkward" behaviour that I didn't understand. Consider the following scenarios:

`select substring('123456',1,3)` returns 123 (which is logical for me)

`select substring('123456',0,1)` returns nothing (I don't know why!)

`select substring('123456',-1,2)` returns nothing too!

**Question:**
Can someone explain how does postgresql substring function behave when we give it 0 or negative values for position.

Comment: What does `select substring('123456', -1, 3)` return, out of interest? I suspect the fact that the indexes are 1-based is relevant here... maybe anything "before" position 1 is just assumed not to exist?

Comment: It definitely doesn't work like Oracle's `SUBSTR` : Refer discussion here https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/12803.1168804636%40sss.pgh.pa.us

Answer (score 2):

The first position in a string is 1. If you do `SUBSTR('abc', 1, 1)` you get `a`. If you do `SUBSTR('abc', 0, 1)`, you get an empty string because there's nothing at position 0. (SUBSTR doesn't raise an exception if the position doesn't exist.) Same for a position of -1, or 10.

These both return `a`: `SUBSTR('abc', 0, 2)`, `SUBSTR('abc', -1, 3)`, which should show pretty much how `SUBSTR` works in postgres. (I'm using SUBSTR but it's the same as SUBSTRING.)

It's worth noting also that arrays in postgres are 1-based rather than 0.

Comment: in your example `SUBSTR('abc', 0, 1)` you say there is nothing at position 0 I would add something, after my tests I can say that it is more appropriate to say `there is nothing at position 0 with length 1` because if you try `SUBSTR('abc', 0, 2)` you get a as a result so I think that postgresql does accept 0 and negative positions because the length defines the result. it would be nice if someone can provide official documentation for my explication (if it is right ofc), I searched and I found nothing.

Comment: Yes well I thought that went without saying given that the length arg used in my example is 1, and a length of 2 from 0 gets the first character. I don't know about any documentation for it but as I said, how it works is quite straightforward if you play with a few edge cases.

Comment: playing some tests gave me almost a clear vision about how it works, I'm just looking for official documentation to confirm my comprehesion, because imagine that we pass a parameter to this function from the application and some value could give unexpected result just because I didn't understand fully how this function works , that's why I need official source =)

Comment: PG will not returns empty because there is no 0 position. It will assume you have, but returns nothing, so `SUBSTR('abc', 0, 2)` equals `SUBSTR('abc', 1, 1)` which returns a, `SUBSTR('abc', 0, 3)` equals `SUBSTR('abc', 1, 2)` which returns ab